# Search for a word in file & print the matching line - Python

Tags: python, search, findall

I am newbie to Python, and I am trying to find a word in the file and print the "entire" matching line

The exmaple.txt has following text:

```
sh version

Cisco IOS Software, 2800 Software (C2800NM-IPBASE-M), Version 12.4(3h), RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc2)

sh inventory

NAME: "2811 chassis", DESCR: "2811 chassis, Hw Serial#: FHK1143F0WY, Hw 
NAME: "High Speed Wan Interface card with 16 RS232 async ports(HWIC-16A)", 
NAME: "High Speed Wan Interface card with 16 RS232 async ports(HWIC-16A)", 
NAME: "16 Port 10BaseT/100BaseTX EtherSwitch"
```

Requirement : 
To find the string "Cisco IOS Software" and if found print that complete line.
Find "NAME:" in the file and if found print that complete line & count the number of occurrences

Code:

```
import re
def image():
    file = open(r'C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Python\10_126_93_132.log', 'r')
    for line in file:
        if re.findall('Cisco IOS Software', line) in line:
            print(line)
        else:
            print('Not able to find the IOS Information information')

def module():
    file = open(r'C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Python\10_126_93_132017.log', 'r')
    for line in file:
        if re.findall('NAME:') in line:
            print(line)
        else:
            print('No line cards found')
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/myname/Desktop/Python/copied.py", line 19, in <module>image()
File "C:/Users/myname/Desktop/Python/copied.py", line 5, in image if re.findall('Cisco IOS Software', line) in line:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list
```

Comment: `re.findall()` returns a list. You can use only `if <string> in line`

Answer (score 6):

Probably that's what you're looking for:

```
import re
with open('some_file', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if re.search(r'some_pattern', line):
            print line
            break
```

See [search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) for more details

BTW: Your question is extremely unreadable. You should check how to post your questions in proper way before you push the ask question button.

Comment: Not working please give proper variables name and references.

Comment: Thank you so much, it helped me.

Comment: To make this answer clearer, you should highlight that you are using the Regular Expression methods before your code.
 - import re

Answer (score 1):

Simple approach:

```
with open('yourlogfile', 'r') as fp:
    lines = fp.read().splitlines()
    c = 0
    for l in lines:
        if 'Cisco IOS Software' in l or 'NAME:' in l:
            print(l)
        if 'NAME:' in l: c += 1
    print('\nNAME\'s count: ', c)
```

The output:

```
Cisco IOS Software, 2800 Software (C2800NM-IPBASE-M), Version 12.4(3h), RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc2)
NAME: "2811 chassis", DESCR: "2811 chassis, Hw Serial#: FHK1143F0WY, Hw 
NAME: "High Speed Wan Interface card with 16 RS232 async ports(HWIC-16A)", 
NAME: "High Speed Wan Interface card with 16 RS232 async ports(HWIC-16A)", 
NAME: "16 Port 10BaseT/100BaseTX EtherSwitch"

NAME's count:  4
```

Comment: Thank for your reply :)